# Simple examples/applications of Bayesian Networks

Tags: matlab, bayesian, bayesian-networks

Thanks for reading.

I want to implement a Baysian Network using the Matlab's BNT toolbox.The thing is, I can't find "easy" examples, since it's the first time I have to deal with BN.

Can you propose some possible applications, (with not many nodes) please ^^ ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Tom Mitchell's "Machine Learning" book, which covers the subject starting with small, simple examples. I suspect there are many course slides you could access online which also give simple examples.

Comment: Yes, in this book the application of Bayesian Networks has been very nicely demonstrated for text classification from the word frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps to start with higher level tools to get a feel for how to construct networks before constructing them in code. Having a UI also allows you to play with the network and get a feel for the way the networks behave (propagation, explaining away, etc).

For example have a look at the free Genie (http://genie.sis.pitt.edu) and its samples, and/or the 50 node limited Hugin-Lite (http://www.hugin.com/productsservices/demo/hugin-lite) with it's sample networks. You can then check your BNT implementations to make sure they verify against the software packages.

Edit: I forgot to mention Netica which is another BN/Influence diagram software package which I think has the biggest selection of examples http://www.norsys.com/netlibrary/index.htm.